# Oracle 11gR2: Can I use DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE to run my custom PL/SQL code?

Tags: plsql, oracle11g, database

I prepared some [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c4522/1/0):

```
CREATE TABLE t_process
    ("process_number" int, "process_status" varchar2(12))
;

INSERT ALL 
    INTO t_process ("process_number", "process_status")
         VALUES (1, 'PROCESSING')
    INTO t_process ("process_number", "process_status")
         VALUES (2, 'PROCESSING')
    INTO t_process ("process_number", "process_status")
         VALUES (3, 'TO_BE_KILLED')
    INTO t_process ("process_number", "process_status")
         VALUES (4, 'PROCESSING')
    INTO t_process ("process_number", "process_status")
         VALUES (5, 'PROCESSING')
    INTO t_process ("process_number", "process_status")
         VALUES (6, 'TO_BE_KILLED')
    INTO t_process ("process_number", "process_status")
         VALUES (7, 'TO_BE_KILLED')
    INTO t_process ("process_number", "process_status")
         VALUES (8, 'WAITING')
    INTO t_process ("process_number", "process_status")
         VALUES (9, 'KILLED')
SELECT * FROM dual
;
```

This is my processing procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE MY_PROCEDURE(IN_ID IN NUMBER) IS
BEGIN
  UPDATE T_PROCESS SET process_status = 'KILLING' WHERE process_number = IN_ID;
  COMMIT;
  -- DO SOME STUFF
  UPDATE T_PROCESS SET process_status = 'KILLED' WHERE process_number = IN_ID;
  COMMIT;
END MY_PROCEDURE;
```

Now I want to use `DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE` to run this custom `SQL`:

```
DECLARE
  id1 number = :id1;
  id2 number = :id2;
BEGIN
  MY_PROCEDURE(id1);
END;
```

So, my question is:

**Can I use `DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE` to execute above SQL statement?**

Because I only found `UPDATE` examples. Maybe `CREATE_CHUNKS_BY_SQL` to select only `TO_BE_KILLED` and then `RUN_TASK` with above statement?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

YES, You can very well do that 11g onwards. I am surprised why it was not suggested here.

You can execute a procedure inside run_task like `begin MY_PROCEDURE( :start_id, :end_id ); end;`

You may need to modify procedure to accept two parameters :start_id, :end_id

Here is the sample code (based on ‘create_chunks_by_rowid’).

```
DECLARE
  l_task     VARCHAR2(30) := 'parallel_processing';
  l_sql_stmt VARCHAR2(32767);
  l_try      NUMBER;
  l_status   NUMBER;
BEGIN
  DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE.create_task (task_name => l_task);

  DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE.create_chunks_by_rowid(task_name   => l_task,
                                               table_owner => 'SCHEMANAME',
                                               table_name  => 'T_PROCESS',
                                               by_row      => TRUE,
                                               chunk_size  => 10000);

  l_sql_stmt := 'begin MY_PROCEDURE( :start_id, :end_id ); end;';

  DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE.run_task(task_name      => l_task,
                                 sql_stmt       => l_sql_stmt,
                                 language_flag  => DBMS_SQL.NATIVE,
                                 parallel_level => 10);

  -- If there is error, RESUME it for at most 2 times.
  l_try := 0;
  l_status := DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE.task_status(l_task);
  WHILE(l_try < 2 and l_status != DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE.FINISHED) 
  Loop
    l_try := l_try + 1;
    DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE.resume_task(l_task);
    l_status := DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE.task_status(l_task);
  END LOOP;

  DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE.drop_task(l_task);
END;
/
```

You can `create chunks` by following means as well based upon your situation / comfort.

`CREATE_CHUNKS_BY_NUMBER_COL`       -- If you want to update by 'process_number'

`CREATE_CHUNKS_BY_SQL`          -- If you think BY_SQL is going to give you a very smaller set of chunks to be processed. Beware of the fact that each chunk will be able to process just 1 row per chunk (*start_id and end_id will same for each chunk*) in this approach.

Comment: One more point, one doesn't need to commit inside one's custom procedure as DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE.run_task will do it automatically !!

Answer (score 2):

No (or at least not without real dirty hacks). If you want to execute PL/SQL in parallel, I've learnt the following options:

1. Use dbms_job. You have already paid for it with the license, many DBA-s understand it and it works reasonable if you don't have too high regulatory, auditing, security or maintenance requirements. You must build that yourself. It has been around since 1995 or so.
2. Use Cronacle of Redwood. It was my first job 20 years ago, sweet memories. It allows you to easily run jobs across a cluster on Oracle using Oracle similar syntax and it is more reliable than dbms_job, has better logging and runs OS-statements too, as well as doing printing. But it costs you money.
3. Use Invantive Scheduler. I work there currently and it is similar to Cronacle, but targeted at administrative systems. And I hate scheduling complex jobs when I do not have easy access to OS, files and especially logging of dbms_output and so.
4. Use application-specific scheduler. For instance the Oracle E-business suite comes with a nice scheduler with security, mutual exclusions, reasonable logging, etc. If you already have such a package, it's use is normally free and your application administrator has experience with it.

When you are a programmer and there is no standard yet and no need for more parallel processing, you could go for dbms_job. When volume increases or when there are more functional requirements, go for a better solution.